# Notebook file corruption

Tags: files-and-directories

For the last few years the beginning of Mathematica notebook files on my computers have been frequently corrupted (Mathematica 11.x on Windows).  If I open them with Windows Notepad the first line or so are nonsense characters. Typically the first text that is not corrupted the CacheID line.  There may also be corrupted lines further into the notebook.  When I open these notebook files with Mathematica, I get the message box entitled "Why the beep?", which says "There appears to be an error in the file names below.  You should close it without saving then check the 'Parse and load entire notebook into memory upon oping' checkbox in the Notebook Options dialog. Name/address of file."  Any ideas what might be causing this?  Thanks much for any help you can provide.

Comment: I have had some success recovering a good portion of corrupted notebooks with [AuthorTools](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12423).

Comment: Do you use special characters? I had similar problems but then I stopped using Turkish characters and it hasn't occurred since then all though I am not sure if this is the real reason.